# understand use of nn.Identity() in model definition using torch

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch

I was understanding the CGAN model given [here](https://github.com/hezhangsprinter/ID-CGAN/blob/master/IDCGAN/models2.lua). 
The generative model has symmetric skip connections as it is explained in the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05957.pdf). Hence, I understand the lines such as:

```
 d2 = {d2_,e4} - nn.CAddTable(true)
```

However, instead of doing the same thing after the last deconv layer d6, the following thing is done:

```
d6 = d61 - nn.Identity()
```

Can someone please help me understand why `nn.Identity()` is used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nn.Identity()` is a module that forwards the input as such. It could be skipped in their code. Nevertheless it seems that they aren't implementing the model they described in figure 3 of their paper. Maybe it performs better without the third skip connection.

Comment: Thank you, as I am new to deep learning and torch framework, I just wanted to have other view.

Answer (score 1):

nn.Identity() is a placeholder identity operator.